# returning 3 arrays from a react custom hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

i have written a custom hook who takes an array and divide it into 3 diffrent arrays.
i dont understand to get back the 3 arrays in the main component.

my main component calling the hook:

```
 const [divide] = useDivideCat();
if(products) { 
  divide(products)
}
```

my "useDivideCat" componenet :

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import  _, { divide } from 'lodash'
import { useMemo, useState , useCallback, memo } from "react"


 const useDivideCat = () => { 
 
  const [main, setMain] = useState([]);
  const [first , setFirst] = useState(['']);
  const [ last, setLast] = useState(['']);
const mainDish=[]
const firstDish=[]
const deseret=[]

const divide = (products) =>  { 
for (var i=0;i<products.length;i++){
 const product = _.get(products, `${[i]}.catagory`);
  if (product=="mainDish") {

    mainDish.push(products[i]);
  }
  else if(product=="firstDish")
   {
    firstDish.push(products[i]);
  }
  else if(product==='deseret')
  {
    deseret.push(products[i]);
 }

  else {
    console.log(products[i].catagory)
  }
}

return mainDish , deseret , firstDish

}
return [divide]

}
export default useDivideCat
```

im open of hearing on diffrent ways of doing the job done
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an array or object in `divide`:

```
return { mainDish, deseret, firstDish };
```

And you can get 3 new arrays like this:

```
if(products) { 
  const { mainDish, deseret, firstDish } = divide(products)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object containing three arrays from the `divide` function like this

```
const divide = () => {
  ...

  return {mainDish , deseret , firstDish}
}
```

And then utilize it in the component like this `{mainDish , deseret , firstDish} = divide(products)`.